# How to inject a service into custom .ts file in Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I have a `form.constants.ts` file:

```
const FORM: Array<IForm> = [
  {
    type: EInputType.DatePicker,
    label: 'DATE_FROM',
    formControlName: 'startDate',
    placeholder: 'ENTER_DATE_FROM',
    value: null
  }
]
```

also I have a `global.helper.service`, and into it have a method that get query params from url:

```
  public getQueryParam () {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      const userId = params['id'];
      console.log(userId);
    });
  }
```

So I need to inject my service `global.helper.service` into my `form.constants.ts` for using `getQueryParam` method in the `form.constants.ts`.

Comment: You should think about inversing your problem. Export the `FORM` and import it inside of your service and use it inside of your `getQueryParams` function or whenever you need it. The problem is, the **form.constants.ts** is not part of angulars dependency tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [Angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services), you can't inject a service somewhere else than a `Class` (e.g.: a Component).

[image]

So you'll need a `Class` with a `constructor` to inject an Angular Service into it.

You can also refer to [the DI part](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) of the documentation.